# Rails 4 render partial based on variable in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, partials

I have 3 different partials and want them displayed in the view at different places depending on the exact product (or record in the database). On a few products, I only want to display 2 of the 3 partials. How would I accomplish this?
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if this requires JS or CSS or if there is a rails solution. I have not tried anything but been looking for a good way to accomplish this.

Comment: Since you want to display partials in the view depending on the exact product (or record in the database) you have to use rails. You can use controller methods for this.

Comment: There are quite a few combinations. What would a controller method look like? Just a case statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some template, say `products/show.html.erb`, which you want to render your partials with your custom logic, I'd suggest just embedding your conditional logic into that template. Here's an example with a lot of assumptions made on my part; feel free to add more details and I can update.

First, your primary template, which I'm assuming is your `show` action:

```
# products/show.html.erb

<h1>Product <%= @product.name %></h1>
<p><%= @product.description %></p>

<% if @product.is_fungible? %>
  <%= render partial: 'products/fungible', locals: { product: @product } %>
<% end %>

<% if @product.is_edible? %>
  <%= render partial: 'products/edible', locals: { product: @product } %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'products/inedible', locals: { product: @product } %>
<% end %>
```

And your partials might look like so (note that, since we've passed in `product` as a local variable, we don't need to use the instance variable `@product` in them:

```
# products/_fungible.html.erb

<p>This product is definitely fungible, by a factor of <%= product.fungibility %>.</p>
```

Comment: That is one solution that works. I also found that I can use the specify the partial as a variable and with that variable referring to the template. <% render partial => product.partialone %> for example where product.partialone is "products/edible".